# ActionBar tabs with overflow button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

Is it possible to put the overflow menu button on the tab bar when using the ActionBar (ActionBarSherlock to be specific)?  I know you can put the overflow button on the normal ActionBar title but that's not what I'm trying to do.  Instead, I'd like to have 4-5 swipeable  tabs and to the right have the overflow button.

Is this possible or can anyone point me to some examples?  I've been looking but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Hey Nick, what is difference between usual ActionBar overflow button that is on the top right and the one which you want to show on the right? Just trying to understand your question.

Comment: They are the same thing.  However, instead of showing it on the actual action bar, I want to show it on the tab bar which is below the action bar.  So the tabs would be on the left, and the overflow button would be on the very far right.